# Checksum expiration

Tags: tokens, checksum

How long is a URL-link using a checksum token from CiviCRM valid?

And can you send multiple emails using same token?

When does the expiration clock start ticking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it myself:

/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

Default setting is 7 days.

Comment: To answer your follow-up - yes, you can send multiple emails with the same checksum, but the clock starts ticking when the checksum is first generated.

Comment: so in that sense it isn't the 'same' checksum, it is just 'a' checksum token.